# how to check if description tag has cdata in php

Tags: php, parsing, xml-parsing, cdata

I have managed to parse through the CDATA to extract relevant img src, and textContent, but I'm wondering if there is a way to detect CDATA in the Description tag

**Edit**: Here is the code I am using

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load($url); // Set the blog RSS feed url here
$feed = array();
    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        $item = array ( 
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'author' => $node->getElementsByTagName('author')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'image' => ''
        );
```

**Edit 2 - Solution** Using var_dump I managed to find that the `firstChild->nodeName` contained cdata info

```
if ( $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeName == '#cdata-section'){}
```

Comment: Your question is lacking any detail. You need to show us the code that you tried, and tag the programming language or environment. Without that we cannot help. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My bad, I thought it would be a generic thing!